# how to get separate color components java?

Tags: java, colors, rgb

Say I have int color... how do i find each red, green, and blue component?

so far I have this piece of code:-

```
int red = rgb & 0xFF0000;

int green = rgb & 0x00FF00;

int blue = rgb & 0x0000FF;
```

I'm stuck with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

create objects of class `Color` to store your color and the class provides methods like 
`getBlue() , getRed() , getGreen()` to retrieve respective component

the class provides a constructor that takes color as `int` , use that and then the above methods.

refer here for detai

[color api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;

int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;

int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Comment: @user1705070 you need to shift the component information to occupy the lowest 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Let color(int rgb)
The first 8 bits of the integer argument are ignored while the last 24 bits define the color -- 8 bits for red, 8 for green, and the last 8 bits for blue.
Ex:color bit pattern be 00000000000000001111111100000000.
represents pure green.
http://cs.roanoke.edu/~cpsc/Fall2011/CPSC120A/lab4/lab4in.html